# Is it possible to display weight of edges of a network using PyVis and Python?

Tags: python, networking, graph, graph-visualization, pyvis

I've read the documentation and I did add edges with attribute `weight` but the weight of edges is not displayed on the plot and it is not displayed when I hover a curses onto the link between two nodes. Is it possible to display weight?

Code snippet (source: https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#networkx-integration):

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import networkx as nx

nx_graph = nx.cycle_graph(10)
nx_graph.nodes[1]['title'] = 'Number 1'
nx_graph.nodes[1]['group'] = 1
nx_graph.nodes[3]['title'] = 'I belong to a different group!'
nx_graph.nodes[3]['group'] = 10
nx_graph.add_node(20, size=20, title='couple', group=2)
nx_graph.add_node(21, size=15, title='couple', group=2)
nx_graph.add_edge(20, 21, weight=5)
nx_graph.add_node(25, size=25, label='lonely', title='lonely node', group=3)
nt = Network('500px', '500px')
# populates the nodes and edges data structures
nt.from_nx(nx_graph)
nt.show('nx.html')
```

Result:
[result of the snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfGHg.png)

**How can I display the weight of an edge?** In this example there is a weight of edge of nodes 20 and 21.

Comment: Could you post a minimal code snippet that shows the problem?

Comment: sure, I'll update it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can supply a `title=` argument to `add_edge()` which will display a tooltip with the label if you hover over the edge:

```py
from pyvis.network import Network

g = Network()
g.add_node(0)
g.add_node(1)
g.add_edge(0, 1, value=5, title="42")  # weight 42
g.show('nx.html')
```

[image]

[Source](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/issues/39)

Comment: I thought about this solution but in my network almost every node has a degree greater than 1

Comment: @Remi How is that a problem? The title is shown over the edge, not the node.

Comment: Ah, my apologizes, you are right. It seems to solve my problem, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help (:

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have tried sending `title` param to `add_edge()` and am not seeing anything show up when clicking on the edge.

Comment: It works, I just tested this snippet again with Python 3.10 and pyvis 0.3.1

Comment: It works in at least Firefox and Edge. Have you looked at the `nx.html` file to see if it mentions your edge label?